# Open Oracle connection failed while using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle, powershell

I'm testing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.1.0 with .Net console application and powershell script, all is fine in my c# application. Unfortunately i have a strange issue with my powershel script while i try to open the oracle connection with the open method.

Here my Powershell "script"

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Oracle\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll'

$CNX = 'Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY = tcp.world)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = HOST)(Port = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SID)));User ID=USER;Password=PWD;'
$con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("$CNX")
$con.open()
```

The error thrown is

> Exception lors de l'appel de « Open » avec « 0 » argument(s) :
>   « Impossible de trouver l'asse mbly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess,
>   Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429
>   c47342'. » Au niveau de C:\oracle\oracle.ps1 : 5 Caractère : 10

The same code written in a c# console application works fine.

I think is a configuration issue, but i'm lost ...

Anyone already have this issue ?

Thx

Comment: My French is poor, but that just says that it cant find the manageddataaccess assembly.  Is the path given a valid path?

Comment: My french is not so poor and I met exactly the same issue with the previous version. The problem was comming from the fact that PowerShell Iwas using was 64 bits and it was unable to load 32 bits assembly.

Comment: The path to the oracle assembly is correct. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll is a any cpu managed assembly so i can load it in 64 bits or 32 bits host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Oracle Managed Data Access assembly only supports .NET 4.0 and above. If you're using Powershell 2.0 then you're on .NET 3.5 or .NET 2.0

You'll need to use Powershell v3 or you could try setting Powershell v2 to use a higher version of .NET as described in this blog post. *Note: This will break some things like remoting*:

http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-newer-versions-of-net-with.html

Alternatively as suggested you could the "semi-Managed" 11g client.

Comment: I'm in powershell 2.0 with a .net 4 framework (i have tweak the powershell.exe.config), with this configuration it's not possible (in my case) to use properly the Oracle Managed Data Access assembly. But i try with Powerhsell 3 and it works fine !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it helps, but here is what is working for me on PowerShell 3.0

I download and install according to the readme text file `ODAC1120320Xcopy_x64.zip` from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html).

Here is my script :

```
# getting good assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\oracle\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"

# Connexion string
$compConStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.213.6.15)(PORT=3000)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MySERVER)));User Id=toto;Password=toto;"

# Establish connexion
$oraConn= New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($compConStr)
$oraConn.Open()
```

---

Here is the code I use to run over the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` :

```
# Download the package if it's not on the disk    
$version = '12.2.1100'
try
{
  if (! $(Test-Path ".\NugetPackages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.$version\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"))
  {
    $ManagedDataAccess = Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess -Destination ".\NugetPackages" -Force -Source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2' -ProviderName NuGet -RequiredVersion $version -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }
  Add-Type -Path ".\NugetPackages\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.$version\lib\net40\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException]
{
  $global:OracleError = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{"StackTrace"=$_.ScriptStackTrace;"Detail" = "Ligne $($_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber) : $($_.exception.message)";"TimeStamp"=([datetime]::Now)}
  $log = $null
}

# Connexion
$oraConn= New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection (($compConStr)
$oraConn.Open()

# Requête SQL
$sql1 = @"
SELECT XX_MYSESSION_ID FROM XX_SILOGIXWSLOG 
  WHERE xx_name='customer_log'
  AND xx_param_4 IS NOT NULL
"@

$command1 = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql1,$oraConn)

# Execution
$reader1=$command1.ExecuteReader()

$n = 0
while ($reader1.read())
{
  $reader1["XX_MYSESSION_ID"]  
}

# Close the conexion
$reader1.Close()
$oraConn.Close()
```

Comment: I'm working with Powershell v2.0 with no future upgrade. I followed your soluton, it works fine but my target is to use the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll. [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/04/use-oracle-odp-net-and-powershell-to-simplify-data-access.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After spending two hours experimenting with other approaches, specifying the connection as a string finally worked for me. I am using Powershell 4.

$tns="Data Source= (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myoracle.server.mydomain)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = myoracle.server.mydomain)));User Id=myid;Password=mypass;"

$con = new-object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($tns)